# If $X,Y \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ independently, find $P(X\leq u,X+Y\leq V)$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

$X,Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$ IID.

(a) Find $F_{X,X+Y}=P(X\leq u,X+Y\leq V)$

(b) Find $f_{X,X+Y}$

My solution :

(a) $$F_{X,X+Y}=P(X\leq u,X+Y\leq v)=P(X\leq u,Y\leq v-x)=P(X\leq u)\cdot P(Y\leq v-x)=(1-e^{-\lambda u})(1-e^{-\lambda(v-u)})=1-e^{-\lambda(v-u)}-e^{-\lambda u}+e^{-\lambda (u+v-u)}=1-e^{-\lambda(v-u)}-e^{-\lambda u}+e^{-\lambda v}$$

(b)$$ f_{X,X+Y}=\frac{d}{d(X)d(X+Y)}F_{X,X+Y}=\frac{d}{d(U)d(V)}F_{U,V}=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda(u-v)}+\lambda e^{-\lambda u}}{dV}  =-\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(u-v)}$$

Is my solution correct? I am not really sure about $(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the following step.

$ \displaystyle P(X\leq u,Y\leq v-x) = P(X\leq u)\cdot P(Y\leq v-x) = \left(1-e^{-\lambda u}\right) \left(1-e^{-\lambda(v-u)}\right)$

Why do you think $P(Y \leq v - x) = \left(1-e^{-\lambda(v-u)}\right)$?

If you want to first find the CDF, note that

$U = X, V = X + Y \implies v \geq u \geq 0~$ as $~x, y \geq 0$

$ \displaystyle P(X\leq u,Y\leq v-x) = \int_0^u \int_0^{v-x} f(x, y) ~ dy ~ dx$

$$ \displaystyle = \lambda^2 \int_0^u e^{-\lambda x} \left[\int_0^{v-x} e^{-\lambda y} ~ dy \right] ~ dx$$

$$ \displaystyle = 1 - e^{- \lambda u} - \lambda u e^{- \lambda v}$$

Now compute pdf from it and you will get the correct answer. Please note the support of pdf is $v \geq u \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda(x+y)},\,x,y\geq 0$.

Let $U=X+Y$, $V=X$.

Then $|J|=1$.

So $f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)|J|$.

So $f_{X+Y,X}(u,v)=\lambda^{2}e^{-\lambda u}\,,v\geq 0,u\geq v$.

From here you can calculate the CDF by integrating.

For the CDF you have to take cases.

if $u'\geq v'$.

Then $$F_{U,V}(u',v')=\int_{0}^{v'}\int_{0}^{u}f_{U,V}(u,v)dvdu+\int_{0}^{v'}\int_{v'}^{u'}f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dudv$$.

And if $u'<v'$ then:-

$$F_{U,V}(u'v')=\int_{0}^{u'}\int_{0}^{u}f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dvdu$$

Comment: Thanks ! I try to get it without Jacobian

Comment: I don't get why my PDF is not as yours , can't see the mistake

Comment: It's because you have made mistakes while computing the CDF. Not to mention that you are getting a negative PDF in a set of non-zero measure. Which by itself should tell you that you have made a mistake.

Comment: You are right ! thanks ! I will be happy to know If I GOT THE IDEA AND THIS PART IS CORRECT : $F_{X,X+Y}=P(X\leq u,X+Y\leq v)=P(X\leq u,Y\leq v-x)=P(X\leq u)\cdot P(Y\leq v-x)$ ? This is a way to solve this problem ? Then I'll know if it is a tiny mistake , maybe plus or minus or something like that

Comment: First of all what is $x$?. You cannot just introduce a variable like that and then use independence. That step is completely wrong.

Comment: The standard way of doing this would be using direct integration , or by using transformations like I did.  First you draw out the region in a paper and then you split cases and then integrate .

Comment: Can you explain me this step please ? $F_{U,V}(u',v')=\int_{0}^{v'}\int_{0}^{u}f_{U,V}(u,v)dvdu+\int_{0}^{v'}\int_{v'}^{u'}f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dudv
$ why  $\int_{0}^{v'}\int_{v'}^{u'}f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dudv
$ is neccessary ?

Comment: You need to integrate over the trapezium formed by $\{u=v,v=v',u=u',u=0\}$. You have to break it into an integral over the square and the triangle. As I said, just draw the graph and you will get it